# I published a website to azure by VS,it works well. when I was trying publish it by VS team service, I got an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I am following a course online to publish a website to azure. when I published by visual studio, it worked well.

[image]

Then I tried to deploy it through visual studio team service, there is an error:

[image: Error message]

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: do you use databases???

Comment: Yes. I use SqlServer DB

Comment: is there those databases? make sure that. and also connection strings

Comment: I published the same connection string to Azure, and the database is same. when I published it by VS, it worked. But when I published it by VS Online, I got an error.

Comment: Compare the sql connection string name in your web config (in VisualStudio) and in your azure web app in Azure Portal (app settings), are they the same ?

Comment: Yes. They are the same.